# take and upload image to blob with python

Tags: python, azure, function, blob

plz help me with this one, i need somehow capture a image or video and upload into blob. In this cenario the imagem will be charge in frond end's page.

i've created a code to upload to blob, but i have no idea how to take it.

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if req.method == "POST" and req.route_params.get('action') == 'uploadFiles':
        try:    
            req_body = req.get_json()
            file_path = req_body.get('file_path')
            blob_name = req_body.get('blob_name') 

            if file_path and blob_name:
                if os.path.exists(file_path):
                    # Upload do arquivo para o Blob Storage
                    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
                        blob_client.upload_blob(file)
                    return func.HttpResponse(f"Arquivo {blob_name} enviado com sucesso.", status_code=200)
                else:
                    return func.HttpResponse("O arquivo não existe.", status_code=400)
            else:
                return func.HttpResponse("Informe o caminho do arquivo e o nome do Blob.", status_code=400)
        except ValueError:
            return func.HttpResponse("O corpo da solicitação não está em formato JSON válido.", status_code=400)
```

i try use flask but, does not work, i wonder if has a simpler way to do, maybe using azure apis.

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes with your code and the image blob uploaded successfully to my storage account container.***

**Code:**

```py
import cv2
import os
import uuid
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def capture_image():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    if ret:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file_name, frame) 
        return file_name
    else:
        return None

def upload_to_blob(file_path, blob_name):
    connection_string = "<storage-conne-string>"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<container-name>")
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(file)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if req.method == "POST" and req.params.get('action') == 'uploadFiles':
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
            file_path = req_body.get('file_path')
            blob_name = req_body.get('blob_name')

            if file_path and blob_name:
                upload_to_blob(file_path, blob_name)
                os.remove(file_path)

                return func.HttpResponse(f"File {blob_name} uploaded successfully.", status_code=200)
            else:
                return func.HttpResponse("Please provide the file path and blob name.", status_code=400)
        except ValueError:
            return func.HttpResponse("The request body is not in valid JSON format.", status_code=400)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse("Unsupported operation.", status_code=405)
```

**reuirement.txt:**

```py
azure-functions
opencv-python
azure-storage-blob
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage-conne-string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

**funxtion.json:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Run** the above **HTTP trigger function** like below,

Click **fn + f5** or Click on **run > Debug**.

**Output:**

***It's run successfully and Worker process started as below,***

[image]

I have the **image in my local path** as below,

[image]

Then, I set the **Post** request in **Postman** with the output **URL** and got the **blob uploaded successfully** to my storage account container as below,

[image]

It gives suceeded output at vs code as below,

[image]

***I got the image blob in my storage account container at Azure portal as below,***

[image]

Now, there's no image in my local path in as below,

[image]